# borrar color input para Wack a mole nivel Ultra Basico

Tags: javascript

estoy haciendo un whack a mole , con mis conocimientos (minimos) apliando lo que se ,entoces me gustaria que ayudarais , ya que , estoy realizandolo de manera muy basica para poder ir mejorandolo poco a poco .
necesito que se me pinten inputs y luego que se me borren , consigo pintarlos en intervalos de un segundo , pero no se como hacer para borrarlos,si podeis facilitarme un forma de borrar el input una vez se pinte segun mi codigo lo agradeceria , ya que ,mejorar el codigo es algo que hare poco a poco , gracias
os paso el codigo :

```
``
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title><strong>Whack a Mole</strong></title>
  <h1>
    <p><strong>Whack a Mole</strong></p>
  </h1>
  <div><input  name="" class="hole"></div>
  <div><input  name="" class="hole"></div>
  <div><input  name="" class="hole"></div>
  <div><input  name="" class="hole"></div>
  <div><input  name="" class="hole"></div>
  <div><input  name="" class="hole"></div>
  <button id="start">START</button>
</head>

<body>
  <script type="text/javascript">



function random (){


var aleatorio = () => { return Math.round(Math.random() * div.length)}

var div = document.getElementsByClassName('hole');
var hole =div[aleatorio()].style.backgroundColor = "yellow "


};



var start = document.getElementById("start")

start.addEventListener("mousedown",function(){

var añadir = setInterval(() => random(), 1000);




});
 
    
  
</script>
</body>

</html>
``
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te propongo dos opciones. La primera sirve si quieres que el tiempo que un `hole` está amarillo sea menor que la duración del intervalo. La segunda opción es más simple pero solo funciona si quieres que el tiempo que cada `hole` está amarillo sea igual a la duración del intervalo.

La primera opción es agregar un timeout para reiniciar el color:

```js
function random (){
    var aleatorio = () => { return Math.round(Math.random() * div.length)}
    var holes = document.getElementsByClassName('hole')
    var hole = holes[aleatorio()]
    hole.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow'
    setTimeout(() => {
        hole.style.backgroundColor = 'white' //O el color que quieras
    }, 500) //Aquí pon el tiempo que quieres que quede amarillo
};
```

La segunda opción sería usar un `forEach` para reiniciar todos antes de cambiar uno a amarillo:

```js
function random (){
    var aleatorio = () => { return Math.round(Math.random() * div.length)}
    var holes = document.getElementsByClassName('hole')
    holes.forEach(hole => {hole.style.backgroundColor = 'white'})
    holes[aleatorio()].style.backgroundColor = 'yellow'
};
```

Comment: muchisimas gracias , listo ....   :)